# Defining a Markov Chain with Infinite States

Tags: probability, markov-chains

**I am trying to learn more about Discrete Time Markov Chains with Infinite State Spaces.**

I am familiar with Discrete Time Markov Chains with Finite State Spaces - now, I am trying to learn about them with Infinite State Spaces.

I spent sometime thinking about how to even define Discrete Time Markov Chains with Infinite State Spaces. Here are some ideas I came up with on my own:

**Example 1:** $S_{t+1}$ is a Discrete Time Markov Chains with Infinite State Space

$$P(S_{t+1} = S_t + 1 | S_t = S_t) = 0.5$$

$$P(S_{t+1} = S_t - 1 | S_t = S_t) = 0.5$$

$$ S_t = 0 \quad \ \text{, When t=0}\ $$

$$S_t, S_{t+1},  t \in \mathbb{Z}$$

**Example 2:** {${X_t, S_t}$ }is a Discrete Time Markov Chains with Infinite State Space

**Part 1:**

- Suppose there are 3 States $S_1$,$S_2$, $S_3$
- Each State is associated with a probability vector (i.e. in terms of $c_i$)
- Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{3} c_i = 1$,  $\sum_{i=4}^{6} c_i = 1$,  $\sum_{i=7}^{9} c_i = 1$
- And $0 < c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5, c_6, c_7, c_8, c_9 < 1$

$$\mathbf{S1} = [ c_1, c_2 , c_3]$$
$$\mathbf{S2} = [ c_4, c_5 , c_6]$$
$$\mathbf{S3} = [ c_7, c_8 , c_9]$$

**Part 2:**

- The probability of being in $S_1$,$S_2$, $S_3$ at time $t$ depends on the state at time $t-1$  (given by a fixed set of probabilities):

$$ P(S(t) = S_i | S(t-1) = S_j) =  
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} \\
p_{31} & p_{32} & p_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$$

- Note that $\sum_{j=1}^{3} p_{1,j} = \sum_{j=1}^{3} p_{2,j}  = \sum_{j=1}^{3} p_{3,j} = 1$
- And $0 < p_{ij} < 1 \quad \text{for all } i,j$

**Part 3:**

- And finally, we define $X_{t+1}$ as:

$$X_{t+1} = 
\begin{cases} 
X_t + 0.05X_t & \text{with probability } S_t(1) \\
X_t - 0.05X_t & \text{with probability } S_t(2), \\
X_t & \text{with probability }S_t(3)). 
\end{cases}$$

$$X_{t+1}, X_{t} \in \mathbb{R}$$

E.g. if at time $t$ we are in State $S_3$, then $S_t(1)  =c_7$, $S_t(2) = c_8$, $S_t(3) = c_9$

**My Question:**

- Have I understood this correctly - are both examples Discrete Time Markov Chains with Infinite State Spaces?
- Suppose we take $X_{t}, S_t$ . Is it possible to answer questions such as : If $X_{t}$ currently has a value of $g_1$, how long on average will it take before $X_{t}$  exceeds a value of $g_1 + g_2$ for the first time? (i.e. time to absorption)

Thanks!

Comment: Example 1 is a (time-homogenous) Markov chain, but in example 2, $(X_t, S_t)$ is a Markov chain. In example 2, $(X_t)$ is not a Markov chain, since you cannot determine the distribution of $X_{t + 1}$ using $X_t$ alone; you need to know $S_t$ to know the transition probabilities from $X_t$ to $X_{t + 1}$.

Comment: @kakashi: thank you for your reply! So in the second example,  {Xt, St} is a markov chain, yes?

Comment: It can be if you want it to, in the sense that there is a unique Markov chain that satisfies your specifications. A Markov chain $(Y_n)_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ is fully specified by it's family of transition probability measures $P_x$ for $x$ in the state space, where intuitively $P_x(A) = P(Y_{n + 1} \in A \mid Y_n = x)$.